# Mostrar un dialogo de alerta en Prolog con XPCE

Tags: prolog, xpce, swi-prolog

```
main:-
    new(Menu, dialog('Diagnostico de medico', size(500,500))),
    new(L, label(nombre,'Bienvenido a su atencion medica')),
```

En la linea 1 me aparece esto:

> Syntax error operator priority clash

Comment: ¿Cuál problema?

Comment: En la linea 1 me aparece esto:                                                            
Syntax error operator priority clash

Answer (score 1):

Si bien no te sé explicar a que se debe el error de precedencia, la forma correcta de mostrar una ventana con un mensaje es en vez de usar `new` y dentro un `label`, usar un `send` y dentro un `label`.

Recuerda que todo se lo estás mandando a tu ventana que se llama `Menu`, así que el `send` tiene sentido allí.

```
:- pce_autoload(file_item, library(file_item)).

main:-
    new(Menu, dialog('Diagnostico de medico', size(900,900))),
    send(Menu, append, label(label,'Bienvenido a su atencion medica')),
    send(Menu, open).
```

[image: resultado visual]

[Fuente](https://manualzz.com/doc/29239605/xpce---swi)